# Can't Scrape Dynamically Loaded HTML Table in an Aspx Website

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from the [Arizona Medical Board](https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/GLSuiteWeb/Clients/AZBOM/public/WebVerificationSearch.aspx?q=azmd&t=20220622082816). I search for Anesthesiology in the specialty dropdown list and I find that the table (with the links to the profiles I want to scrape) are dynamically loaded into the website. I notice when hitting the 'specialty search' button, a POST request is made to the server and the html table is actually returned from the server. I have tried simulating this post request to see if I get receive this html table and then try to parse it with bs4. Is this possible, and if so, am I even on the right track?

I have tried to included the form data I found in the network tab of the developer tools but I am not sure if this is the right data, or if I am forgetting some data here or in the header.

Please let me know if I need to clarify, I understand this may not be worded the best. Thank you!

```
import requests
# import re
import formdata

session = requests.Session()

url = "https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/GLSuiteWeb/Clients/AZBOM/public/WebVerificationSearch.aspx?q=azmd&t=20220622123512"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'My-Agent-Placeholder'}

res = session.get(url, headers=headers)

print("Response: {}".format(res))

payload = {
  "__VIEWSTATE": formdata.state,
  "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": formdata.generator,
  "__EVENTVALIDATION" : formdata.validation,
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Name": 'rbName1',
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Name": "rbName1",
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtLastName" : '', 
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtFirstName" : '',
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24License": "rbLicense1",
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtLicNum": '',
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Specialty": "rbSpecialty1",
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlSpecialty": '12155',
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddlCounty": '15910',
  "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtCity": '',
  "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24btnSpecial",
  "__EVENTARGUMENT": ''  
}

# params = {"q": "azmd",
# "t": "20220622123512"}

# #url = "https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/GLSuiteWeb/Clients/AZBOM/Public/Results.aspx"

res = session.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print("Post response: {}".format(res))
print(res.text)

# res = requests.get('https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/GLSuiteWeb/Clients/AZBOM/Public/Results.aspx', headers=headers)
```

Comment: If the web page contains javascript that dynamically creates page content, then you can't use `requests`.  You have to use something that acts like a real browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0"
}

url = "https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/GLSuiteWeb/Clients/AZBOM/public/WebVerificationSearch.aspx?q=azmd&t=20220622082816"

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

    data = {}
    for inp in soup.select("input"):
        data[inp.get("name")] = inp.get("value", "")

    data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Name"] = "rbName1"
    data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$License"] = "rbLicense1"
    data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Specialty"] = "rbSpecialty1"
    data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSpecialty"] = "12155"
    data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlCounty"] = "15910"

    data["__EVENTTARGET"] = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSpecial"
    data["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = ""

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )
    for row in soup.select("tr:has(a)"):
        name = row.select("td")[-1].text
        link = row.a["href"]

        print("{:<35} {}".format(name, link))
```

Prints:

```
Abad-Pelsang, Elma A.               https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/glsuiteweb/clients/azbom/Public/Profile.aspx?entID=1620623&licID=121089&licType=1
Abadi, Bilal Ibrahim                https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/glsuiteweb/clients/azbom/Public/Profile.aspx?entID=1755530&licID=525771&licType=1
Abbasian, Mohammad                  https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/glsuiteweb/clients/azbom/Public/Profile.aspx?entID=1635449&licID=492537&licType=1
Abdel-Al, Naglaa Z.                 https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/glsuiteweb/clients/azbom/Public/Profile.aspx?entID=1637612&licID=175204&licType=1
Abedi, Babak                        https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/glsuiteweb/clients/azbom/Public/Profile.aspx?entID=1641219&licID=169009&licType=1
Abel, Martin D.                     https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/glsuiteweb/clients/azbom/Public/Profile.aspx?entID=1624271&licID=510929&licType=1
Abenstein, John P.                  https://azbomprod.azmd.gov/glsuiteweb/clients/azbom/Public/Profile.aspx?entID=1622930&licID=502482&licType=1

...and so on.
```

Comment: This definitely works, I really appreciate it. I was wondering if you could explain this a little bit so I can understand where I went wrong. I understand the static data you sent through the dictionary but why did you need to use the get request to get the input values. Is it because they change each time?